# resize html website for different screen resolutions

Tags: html, css

I had to redo a website from flash to html/jquery.
Everything looked great. Until I tested the site on a netbook where the screen resolution is much smaller. All the elements were misaligned or didn't stretch as I wanted it to. Or there were scroll bars everywhere.

So, How would do I make it stretch or resize properly,

Is there a property which I can set somewhere that would resize everything proportionately?

Comment: Use percentage-based width values, avoid floats like the plague.

Comment: You can also use `@media` in your `CSS` to match your styles with all resolutions. check this http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/common-techniques-in-responsive-web-design.html#fbid=q3_-oSNiotY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use heigh / width in percentage(%) rather px / em. change the css file.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a property which I can set somewhere that would resize everything proportionately?

No, I wish :P You'll need to redo the layout to make it [liquid](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/) or use media queries to make it [responsive](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) to different resolutions. I'm afraid both solutions could be pretty complex.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a property which I can set somewhere that would resize everything proportionately?

Everything? No. Font sizes won't adjust based on window size (at least not without JS).

You can set the widths of most things using percentage units in your stylesheets, but even then there will be a point where things will break down.

The current buzzword is [responsive web design](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/awesome-tutorials-to-master-responsive-web-design) (I can't comment on the quality of the links from that page) in which [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) are used to provide different designs for different sized browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The property called `Media Query` we mostly use this property with  [Responsible Web Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/). In which we tell browsers change the specific `css` property at that particular `screen size`.

Check this article for more http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

& for `Responsible Web Design` mostly use value in `Percentage` instead of `Pixels` .

Check [THIS](http://mediaqueri.es/) website for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no "magic" which scales things up/down. i can think of some guidelines:

1. Use relative widths for things (percentages) instead of absolute value
2. no hardwired sizes, keep them in separate CSS documents
3. work your way *up*: choose a minimum resolution, work upwards from it. it makes sizing things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The question was to RESIZE not to REALIGN. Using percentiles will only change WHERE the HTML elements show up on the page. It will not change their SIZE.

Comment: This should probably be a comment. It does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use with and height in percentage to set your screen for all resoulation..Give the 100% width to the body and the div you want give 100% width.